# Hi, How to Use for loops in my sql , to print concat() column values of two Tables?

Tags: mysql

```
CREATE procedure mydbase.while_example2()

wholeblock:BEGIN

  declare str VARCHAR(255) default '';

declare x1 int default 0; 

  declare x STRING default NULL;
  declare y STRING default NULL;

  SET x = SELECT*FROM stems;

  SET y = SELECT*FROM suffixs;

  WHILE x1 <= 5 DO

    SET str = CONCAT(str,x,'y');

    SET x1 = x1 + 1;

  END WHILE;

  select str;

END//

mysql> call while_example2();//
```

Comment: Can you please provide table details or how to join both table?

Comment: @ shola table 1 is- create table stems(stem varchar(100)); 
table 2 is - create table suffixs(suffix varchar(100));
int y = total no. of values in stem column
int j = total no. of values in suffix column
wordset = stems(i)+suffixs(k); (take for loop int i =0,int k=0,i<y,k<j )
print wordset

Answer (score 1):

You can use group_concat to concat different columns if i get your requirement correctly.

http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-group_concat/

Comment: table 1 is- create table stems(stem varchar(100)); table 2 is - create table suffixs(suffix varchar(100)); int y = total no. of values in stem column int j = total no. of values in suffix column wordset = stems(i)+suffixs(k); (take for loop int i =0,int k=0,i<y,k<j ) print wordset

Comment: Using for loop on each varchar type columns of two table i=0 and k= 0; (in condition take total no of values in column)
col1(0)+col(k)= wordset;
i++;
k++;